# sql запрос с выборкой из одного столбца в одну строку в таблице

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы "Расписание" и "Дисциплины", в расписании есть 4 столбца, значение которых, является номером в таблице "Дисциплины", необходимо сделать выборку так, чтобы в выходной таблице вместо номеров были названия из таблицы "Дисциплины", с одним наименованием получается, а вот два и более уже не выходит

Comment: Надо использовать столько копий второй таблицы, сколько ссылок на неё из первой. Т.е. 4 копии, каждая связывается по своему полю первой таблиты.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ дан в комментариях пользователем Akina

```
SELECT table_rasp.GroupName, Less1.Name, Less2.Name, Less3.Name, Less4.Name FROM table_rasp,table_lessons as "Less1",table_lessons as "Less2",table_lessons as "Less3", table_lessons as "Less4" WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson1 = Less1._id and table_rasp.Lesson2=Less2._id and table_rasp.Lesson3=Less3._id and table_rasp.Lesson4=Less4._id)
```